# iOS MKMapKit regionDidChangeAnimated

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate

I would like to determine the minimum + maximum visible latitude and longitude values in the [MKMapViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html) delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

A function like `isCoordinateInRegion` would come in handy.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [`MKMapRectContainsPoint`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008209-CH2-SW31). You can get the `MKMapRect` using `visibleMapRect` property of the `MKMapView` object and `MKMapPoint` using [`MKMapPointForCoordinate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKitFunctionsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008209-CH2-SW11).